# lmfit.Model.fit() not working in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, lmfit

I am using lmfit to fit a series of spectra. My model is a sum of several spectral lines and a constant term. I want to use multiprocessing.Pool to fit many spectra simultaneously. The fit works very well when used in a for loop but seems to fail when using multiprocessing.Pool.

My model is fairly complicated, so I apologize for that, but hopefully this is clear enough. I know it's odd to have a function within a function, but I've found that this is the only way to get lmfit.Model() to run correctly.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
from lmfit.models import ConstantModel

def fit_spectrum(spectrum):
    xdata, ydata = spectrum
    def line_profile(x, amp1, amp2, a, center, wave1, wave2, sig1, sig2, N):
        gauss1 = amp1*np.exp(-(x-wave1)**2/(2*sig1**2.))
        gauss2 = amp2*np.exp(-(x-wave2)**2/(2*sig2**2.))
        core = gauss1 + gauss2

        w = center/N_eff * (1/(np.sqrt(2)*np.pi))
        t = w**2.
        b = ((x-center)**2+w**2)
        scatter = a*t/b

        return core + scatt

    mod = None
    spectral_lines = [ 391.44,  404.71,  435.92,  546.15,  557.89,  589.15,  589.75, 630.2 ]
    for i, line in enumerate(spectral_lines):
        pref = 'f%s_' % str(i).zfill(4)
        line_model = Model(line_profile, prefix=pref)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'amp1', value=10, min=0)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'amp2', value=10, min=0)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'center', value=line, min=line-.1, max=line + .1, vary=True)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'delta1', value=0.06, min=0, max=0.1, vary=True)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'delta2', value=0.09, min=0, max=0.1, vary=True)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'wave1', expr=pref+'center + '+pref+'delta1')
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'wave2', expr=pref+'center - '+pref+'delta2')

        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'a', value=10, min=0)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'sig1', value=0.1, min=0, max=1)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'sig2', value=0.1, min=0, max=1)
        line_model.set_param_hint(pref+'N', value=83200, min=0)

        if mod is None:
            mod = line_model
        else:
            mod = mod + line_model

    offset = ConstantModel()
    offset.set_param_hint('c', value=1)

    model = mod + offset
    params = model.make_params()

    results = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
    return results
```

Now, I have a list of many spectra that I'd like to fit through multiprocessing. If I run the function fit_spectrum() in a for loop, the fitting is successful. Here's an example of code that works, where spectrum is a list of a numpy array of wavelength and data, spectrum = [np.array(wavelength), np.array(data)], and list_of_spectra is a list of these:

```
FitResults = []
for spectrum in list_of_spectra:
    result = fit_spectrum(spectrum)
    FitResults.append(result)
```

When I try to implement this in multiprocessing, the code just stalls at Model.fit(). There is no error message nor does the code crash. It just moves on to the next spectrum without returing the fit results. Nothing is returned and when the program comes to the end of list_of_spectra, the code hangs.

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
FitResults = pool.map(fit_spectrum, list_of_spectra)
pool.terminate()
```

I think perhaps this has something to do with the need for multiprocessing to pickle, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I also found this problem implementing the lmfit.minimize() function instead of Model.fit() with some changes to the code above.

Comment: Fitting with lmfit uses many Python features that are not pickleable.   You might try the `dill` package..

Comment: I ran the code using `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool` which uses the `dill` package. There was no change in the behavior. The `pathos.dill` documentation says that dill still can't serialize these: frame, generator, traceback. Does lmfit.Model.fit() use one of these standard types?

Comment: As I said, lmfit uses many Python features such as methods called from compiled code that are not easily pickled.